# Oracle Client 12c

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to connect to a remote oracle database without using Oracle client in my local machine?

Comment: What if I use a SQL developer tool?

Comment: sql developer tool is a client as well!

Comment: So if I install oracle SQL developer tool or toad,no need to explicitly install oracle Client right?

Comment: You can install SQL developer without having an Oracle client installed because it uses the thin JDBC driver to connect.  Every TOAD install I have seen relies on having the Oracle client installed because it uses the Oracle client libraries to connect.

Comment: @maniramreddy you don't need to install separate client driver , since it has its own built in client

Answer (score 2):

So how would you envision connecting to a database (any database) without *some* sort of "client"?

Every database product (oracle, mssql, mysql, etc. etc.) has its own unique, proprietary interface. This means they each require their own unique client software stack. Some user interface programs (like Toad, just to pick one example) provide only the user interface and rely on the separate installation of the database's client software. Oracle's own SQL Developer can use the separate client software stack, or its own built-in JDBC drivers.

It comes down to exactly what you are trying to accomplish, so re-read my opening question back to you.